# Updating Thinkpad X200 BIOS

Tags: bios, thinkpad

How do I update the BIOS on a Thinkpad X200 running Linux?  Seems updates require Windows.

Comment: If you're interested, coreboot appears to support that model https://www.coreboot.org/Board:lenovo/x200

Comment: @mttpgn, yes, I'm waiting for my SOIC clip to arrive.  But I read somewhere that it's a good idea to run Lenovo's BIOS update first, which includes an EC-firmware update.

Answer (score 1):

Since you may find it difficult to boot from a CD on an X200, it might be more useful to write the update to a USB stick:

- download [the appropriate CD image](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/downloads/ds015007)

  ```
  wget https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/6duj48us.iso
  ```
- download [the El Torito extraction tool](https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~krienke/ftp/noarch/geteltorito/):

  ```
  wget https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~krienke/ftp/noarch/geteltorito/geteltorito/geteltorito
  chmod 755 geteltorito
  ```
- use it to extract the bootable image:

  ```
  ./geteltorito -o bios.img 6duj48us.iso
  ```
- insert a USB stick, and write the image to the stick (**use the appropriate device below**, and note that this will overwrite the data on your USB stick):

  ```
  cat bios.img > /dev/sdh
  sync
  ```

  (replacing `sdh` with the appropriate device)
- reboot, and boot from the USB stick to update your BIOS.

Later Thinkpads can be updated automatically [using `fwupd`](https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2018/08/06/please-welcome-lenovo-to-the-lvfs/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions.  When I do this, my Thankpad says 'Missing operating system'.

Comment: Weird... I updated a T450s yesterday using this technique. What does `cmp bios.img /dev/sdh` output?

Comment: mounted:
# cmp bios.img /dev/sdb
bios.img /dev/sdb differ: byte 16422, line 5

not mounted:
# cmp bios.img /dev/sdb
cmp: EOF on bios.img after byte 38797312, in line 64739

Comment: You ran `cmp` twice and it gave different results?

Comment: yes before and after unmounting